# PYTHON: Identify Non-English words in a Pandas dataframe using enchant library

Tags: python, pandas, text, nlp

I like working with `pandas` due to my affinity to `tidyverse` in `R` when dealing with tables. I have a table of about 200,000 rows and need to replace punctuations and extract non-English words, and put it another column named `non_english` in the same table. I prefer using `enchant` library because I found it more accurate than using `nltk` library. My dummmy table `df` has `dundee` column which I am working on. A dummy data is as thus:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'dundee':    ["I love:Marae", "My Whanau is everything",  "I love Matauranga", "Tāmaki Makaurau is Whare", "AOD problem is common"]})
```

My idea is to remove punctuation first, write a function to extract non-english words, and then apply the function to the dataframe, but I got this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import enchant
import re
import string

# remove punctuations
df['dundee1'] = df['dundee'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', ' ')

# change words to lower case
df['dundee1'] = df['dundee1'].str.lower()


# Function to check if a word is english
def check_eng(word):
    
    # use all available english dictionary
    en_ls = ['en_NZ', 'en_US', 'en_AU', 'en_GB']
    en_bool = False
            
    # check all common dictionaries if word is English 
    for en in en_ls:
        dic = enchant.Dict(en)
        if word != '':
            if dic.check(word) == True:
                en_bool = True
                break

    disp_non_en = ""
    word = word.str.split(' ')

    if len(word) != 0:
        if en_bool == False:
             disp_non_en = disp_non_en + word + ', '

    return disp_non_en

df['non_english'] = check_eng(df['dundee1'])
```

The desired table is this:

```
    dundee                          non_english
0   I love:Marae                    Marae
1   My Whanau is everything         Whanau
2   I lov Matauranga                love, Matauranga
3   Tāmaki Makaurau is Whare        Tāmaki Makaurau, Whare
4   AOD problem is common           AOD
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the call:

```
check_eng(df['dundee1'])
```

where `df['dundee1']` is of type `Series` and you have an if statement trying to elicit the Boolean value of:

```
 if word != '':
```

`word` is a `Series` so you should rather use:

```
df['dundee1'].apply(check_eng)
```

instead.

There is one more issue in the `check_eng`:

Instead of:

```
 if len(word) != 0:
        if en_bool == False:
             disp_non_en = disp_non_en + word + ', '
```

You should rather use:

```
words = word.str.split(' ')
for word in words:
    if en_bool == False:
        disp_non_en = disp_non_en + word + ', '
```

because you do:

```
word = word.str.split(' ')
```

which changes the type of `word` from `str` to `list` and makes the `if` invalid.

You may want to review some other aspects of the error: [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Thanks @sophos. I have changed ```check_eng(df['dundee1'])``` to ```f['dundee1'].apply(check_eng)```,  but there is an error  ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: sorry, you are wrong here. The issue is in the type of `word` that changes in the function. Pointed it out in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

remove str from word.str.split(' '), it will work fine.
Try this:
words = word.split(' ')